# How can I remove exhaust pipe cover that's sealed with silicone?

Tags: bathroom, removal, exhaust-fan, cover, silicone

I want to remove and replace the exhaust pipe cover shown in the picture below, but I can't get it off.

The wall is made up of (in the order from outer most material to the inner most material:

- Ceramic tiles
- Membrane (the kind you apply with a paint brush)
- 12 mm [Wet room boards](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/eb/a7/1f/eba71f62be00578f8a099769a2ada8f0.jpg)
- 10 mm Pine panel wall (for strength)
- Glass wool insulation

There is a pipe coming from the fan engine that stops a ~4-5 centimeters from the outer wall layer. In order to protect the inside of the wall against moist, wet room silicone was used to cover all the places where moist could enter the wall. Unfortunately, it seems the cover was put in place while the silicone was still wet, and now I can't get it off.

[image]

Do you have any tips for how I can remove it, without risking to damage the wall. I can buy a new cover, so if I have to break it, that's fine.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, you should be able to unclip the inner square (with the louvres in it) from the surround. That should get you better access to the inside.

After that, I've found a knife works best.

Comment: Or the frame pops off, from the perimeter of the louvers,  it may be covering screws.

Comment: I'll give it a try... I'll hopefully click "accept" in a few days :)